# Is there an API available for Google's Related Search Queries?

Tags: google-search, related-content

When I search for `Clooney` at google.com a number of related search queries are suggested at the bottom:

```
Searches related to clooney
clooney movies
clooney girlfriend
rosemary clooney
nick clooney
clooney oscar
obama clooney
clooney fundraiser
betty clooney
```

I would like to receive this list programmatically for a single or a list of keywords. Is any such API available?

Comment: I'm surprised someone would like to close this question. The problem is extremely clear and concise: a list of related search queries needs to be requested with the help of an API. The question is whether such API is available, which simply cannot be answered in an opinionated manner. Therefore I vote for this question to be re-opened.

Comment: Second it. Voted to reopen the question.

Comment: Community has spoken - reopened.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately, Google has sunset the [Related Queries](https://developers.google.com/shopping-search/v1/reference-content-module-related-queries) API. There are similar and semi-similar APIs though.

I am not affiliated with any of these, and haven't used any of them.

[Similarweb](https://developer.similarweb.com/similar_sites) provides an API to find domains that are similar to passed domains. It's not the same as search *terms*, but if you know which *domains* you wish to compare, that is an option. It is not a free service though.

Another pay service is from [KeywordDiscovery](http://www.keyworddiscovery.com/subscribe-keyword-search-related.html) and their [related](http://www.keyworddiscovery.com/tour-related.html) keywords.

[Yahoo!](http://developer.yahoo.com/boss/search/boss_api_guide/related.html) provides a related search service. It is not [free](http://developer.yahoo.com/boss/search/#pricing), and will return 10 results per query. This is part of their [BOSS](http://developer.yahoo.com/boss/search/) search product.

Comment: re: Yahoo BOSS "At Yahoo, we’re always looking for ways to streamline and simplify products for our customers. With this focus in mind, we will discontinue the BOSS JSON Search API on March 31, 2016."

Answer (score 26):

No, Google doesn't have any public API that you can use to retrieve a list of related URLs programmatically. But if you can settle for an alternative, then Bing has a public API for a similar purpose:

```
http://api.bing.com/osjson.aspx?query=clooney
```

Answer (score 8):

The [Freebase API](https://developers.google.com/freebase/) is an open source knowledge graph that contains the publicly available part of the knowledge base that Google uses to populate there related queries list.

*It is actually released by Google however contains only a subset of there full knowledge graph due to legal restrictions from some of there data sources*.

Search results can be queried programmatically using HTTP and JSON or there is a variety of programming language [client libraries](https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/libraries)

Here is the default [JSON result](https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?indent=true&query=clooney) for the 'clooney' example given in the question. Which could be filtered via the API and used as seeds for branching the search depending on the usecase.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  The Freebase API doesn't include any information on related search queries.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the Google Webmaster Tools. It has a bunch of methods that help manage queries!

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en