# API for Google 'People Also Search For' - Android

Tags: android, freebase, google-search-api, google-knowledge-graph

As the [Freebase API](https://developers.google.com/freebase/) is deprecated, and i used the [KnowledgeGraph API](https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/) to get the list of '**People also search for**' , but the requirement is not fulfilled,

[image]

Please suggest an API to get the results. and also i followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23030298/is-there-an-api-to-get-results-similar-to-googles-people-also-search-for) but there is no answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23030298/is-there-an-api-to-get-results-similar-to-googles-people-also-search-for), or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655207/is-there-an-api-available-for-googles-related-search-queries).

Your question is a little vague - what requirements weren't fulfilled? - but here's a list of possibles (some are not free):

- [Yahoo's BOSS service](https://developer.yahoo.com/boss/search/boss_api_guide/related.html)
- [Similar Web](https://developer.similarweb.com/similar_websites_api) - Up to 20 results
- [Keyword Discovery](http://www.keyworddiscovery.com/kd-api-information.html)
- [A tool for KnowledgeGraph](https://github.com/ahmadassaf/KBE)
- [Interest Graph](https://github.com/srgkm/interest-graph) is currently in development

But KnowledgeGraph is the [official replacement](https://plus.google.com/+GerwinSturm/posts/REozHKrm9fQ) for Freebase.